# Windows Scheduler not writing application logs in to log file

Tags: java, scheduled-tasks, windows-task-scheduler, java-batch

I have java program with Main method for generating file every 1 hour , and a batch program to start this program. When I start this program using batch program from command prompt, application generating file and LOGS files also updating  . All good.

But when I start running this application using windows Task scheduler , application generating file , but LOGS are not updating in LOG file.

Running this task with logged in user also.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/czNr9.png)

Any permission issue ...

tried with providing full right permission for the user to the logs file and directory .

Comment: Try filling in that *Start in* dialog to the directory where you expect to find your logs